# Filter and delete data

Tags: excel, vba

In a Excel sheet I have data from column A1 to G12.

In the C column I have employee ID. I need to filter certain employee ID and delete those rows.

Example: Filter three employee ID 51168, 79783 and 70682 and delete.

I recorded a macro. If the particular employee ID is not in the place means it is deleting some other row.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
"51168", "70682", "79783"), Operator:=xlFilterValuesRows("2:2").Select
Range("C2").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$9").AutoFilter Field:=3
```

Answer (score 0):

just execute the filter first,
select the results and use the "**EntireRow**" keyword to delete the entire row.

something like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array( _
"51168", "70682", "79783"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

also its worth making sure you have at least one result before you delete all empty rows for no reason.

Comment: I have doubt in this code. When i execute this, it will not delete other rows right?

Comment: You could always test it with a message box first.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon all rows in between will be deleted too, including hidden; as the list is not that long, you might want try to delete rows with the following trick after filtering

```
For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next
```